# Android Studio gradle Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I tried to sync my project all libraries return 400 error code.

for example :

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:classpath'.
Could not download gradle-retrolambda.jar (me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0)
Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/me/tatarka/gradle-retrolambda/3.7.0/gradle-retrolambda-3.7.0.jar'.
Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/me/tatarka/gradle-retrolambda/3.7.0/gradle-retrolambda-3.7.0.jar'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
```

Comment: Did you follow the guide on the github page (particularly the classpath and buildscript setup)? https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone who has my problem.i fixed the issue by deleting proxies was set in `gradle.properties` file

Comment: Have no proxy settings. Can download pom and jar from browser, but get 400 in gradle build.

Comment: @JohnSmith r u able to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
Check to see if the agent has been set up for your computer's C:\Users\***\.gradle gradle.properties file.Delete the last four lines if you have the following code.

systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.proxyHost=mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn
systemProp.https.proxyHost=mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
```